# What language is used here?

Tags: find

[Click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x9hC.jpg)

It's my first time to see this language and I really wonder what language it is.
This language is being used in a PLC program  which is called OMRON

Comment: If you have this code on your computer, please copy and paste it in the question. Don't upload pictures.

Comment: Downvoted for not properly editing the question. See: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this code uses the [Structured Text (ST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_text) programming language.

The OMRON program supports all of the following languages:

- Ladder diagram (LD)
- Sequential Function Charts (SFC)
- Function Block Diagram (FBD)
- Structured Text (ST)
- Instruction List (IL)

These are based on the [IEC_61131-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61131-3) international standard for PLC programming.